# Can i have two action servlets in an html form?

Tags: servlets

```
<form action="LoginServlet" method="post">
            Username: <input type="text" name="username">
            Password: <input type="password" name="password">
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
```

I need to retrieve the 'username' parameter in 'ChangePasswordServlet' as well.
Please help me with the format. I have tried searching for it but did not find any solution.

Comment: <form action="LoginServlet" method="post" action="ChangePasswordServlet" method="post">

would this be correct?

Comment: You can have multiple submit buttons, with different `formaction` attributes to specify the servlet.

Comment: You can't have duplicate attributes in a tag.

Comment: so i need to have two submit buttons ?

Comment: No, yo can't... create a class with the generic functions and invoke it from the servlets you need.

Answer (score 0):

Add a second button for changing the password:

```
<input type="submit" value="Change Password" formaction="ChangePasswordServlet">
```